# FFMPEG build for android on ubuntu

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk, ffmpeg

> I am developing a media app which provides support for all video formats for implementing this feature we require FFMPEG the very best library for codecs. Compiling FFMPEG on windows for android is very long battle so I migrated to ubuntu I have almost compiled it shows the the binaries but it gives at last point following message

```
>AR libpostproc/libpostproc.a
AR  libswresample/libswresample.a
AR  libswscale/libswscale.a
AR  libavcodec/libavcodec.a
AR  libavutil/libavutil.a
INSTALL libavfilter/libavfilter.a
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
INSTALL libavresample/libavresample.a
INSTALL libpostproc/libpostproc.a
INSTALL libswresample/libswresample.a
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.a
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.a
LD  ffmpeg_g
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.a
CP  ffmpeg
STRIP   ffmpeg
skipping strip ffmpeg
INSTALL install-progs-yes
INSTALL ffmpeg
/home/akshay/Desktop/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: -: unknown option
```

> Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/akshay/Desktop/android-ndk-r9c
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86
PREFIX=./android-ffmpeg
function build_one
{
    ./configure --target-os=linux --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-asm \
    --arch=arm \
    #--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --disable-stripping \
    #--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-version3 \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-gpl \
    --disable-doc \
    --enable-avresample \
    --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
    --enable-muxer=rtsp \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --enable-encoders \
    --enable-decoders \
    --enable-protocols \
    --enable-hwaccels \
    --enable-zlib \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --extra-cflags="-I/home/android-ffmpeg/include -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/home/android-ffmpeg/lib"
    make -j4 install
    $PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
    $PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -  nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavfilter/     libavfilter.a libavresample/libavresample.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -  llog --warn-once --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/libgcc.a
}
build_one
```

Please tell me anything wrong in the script

Comment: The error is telling you that it is taking `$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/libgcc.a` as an option.  Try putting it on a separate line, or place `&&` before it to tell it to proceed to that command only if the previous one was successful

Comment: @nathanaizemore it show the same statement by trying ur comment

Answer (score 2):

you have an unused '-' after `-ldl`. The empty space between '-' and 'llog' must be ommited.

Comment: there is another one before notstdlib (bloat space must be ommited).